# Is the SherlockAndAnagrams algorithm on HackerRank explained wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, hashtable

here is a link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-anagrams/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps

**This is the part I don't agree with:**

There are 6 anagrams of the form [k,k] at positions[[[0],[1]],[[0],[2]],[[0],[3]],[[1],[2]],[[1],[3]]

and [[2],[3]] .

There are 3 anagrams of the form [kk,kk] at positions [[0,1],[1,2]],[[0,1],[2,3]]  and [[1,2],[2,3]] .

There is 1 anagram of the form [kkk,kkk] at position [[0,1,2],[1,2,3]] .

**The reason I don't think the explination is correct is because:**

1- The form [kk,kk] we have more anagrams [[0,1],[0,2]],[[0,1],[0,3]],[[1,2],[1,3]]

2- The form [kkk,kkk] we have more anagrams [[0,1,2],[0,2,3]], [[0,1,2],[0,1,3]] and so on.

Do I understand the problem wrong or did the author made an error?

Please note that in his explination above, he didn't use anagrams in order only, so I'm wondering why he didn't use the anagrams I found?

Comment: The anagrams you found are not *substrings*. A substring is contiguous, unlike a *subsequence*.

Comment: Great, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Two strings are anagrams of each other if the letters of one string
>   can be rearranged to form the other string. Given a string, find the
>   number of pairs of substrings of the string that are anagrams of each
>   other.

You should read the definition of anagrams given in the link carefully. The author did not make an error.